# How to get rid of Cross-Origin Request Blocked: in rails 4

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, cors, rack-cors

Can you please tell me where I have gone wrong and is there anything left out that I has to add to fetch the json from heroku site

config.ru

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)

run Rails.application
use Rack::Cors do
allow do
origins 'localhost:3000', '127.0.0.1:3000', 'http://stark-anchorage-86169.herokuapp.com/ages/    getfortest', /\Ahttp:\/\/192\.168\.0\.\d{1,3}(:\d+)?\z/


resource '/file/list_all/', :headers => 'x-domain-token'
resource '/file/at/*',
    :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :patch, :options, :head],
    :headers => 'x-domain-token',
    :expose  => ['Some-Custom-Response-Header'],
    :max_age => 600

end

 allow do
 origins '*'
 resource '/public/*', :headers => :any, :methods => :get
 end
 end
```

config/application.rb

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module AppV11
class Application < Rails::Applications.



config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true

config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
end

end
```

My Controller looks like this with some helpers below

```
before_filter :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://staranchorage-          86169.herokuapp.com/ages/getfortest'
end
```

The Angularjs part:

```
function getpost()
 {
     console.log("INSIDE GETPOST");
     $http.get('http://stark-anchorage-86169.herokuapp.com/ages/getfortest')
     .success(function(response)
             {
         console.log("INSIDE RESPONSE "+ response);
         $scope.demogetpost = response.data;
         console.log( $scope.demogetpost);
         console.log("NOT PRINTING");
     })
     return $scope.demogetpost;
 }
```

Comment: Missing a variety of headers that are easily found doing a search for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. I don't know rails but I'm sure there must be gems for this

Comment: Thanks it worked @charlietfl

Comment: Suggest you add your own answer as to how you solved this. Might help others in future

Comment: I have been opening in my page in new tab. That's the problem why I got that error

Answer (score 0):

I have been opening in new tab and that's the reason why I got Cross-Origin request blocked. Also I have added headers for Access-Control-Allow-Origin.